# Visual Studio Build error Project file does not exist

Tags: asp.net-web-api, msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, dacpac

I have a build definition setup to deploy my Visual Studio project to Azure. This has been working for over a year now but suddenly I am getting this error. MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

I am selecting the solution file as the solution target for the Visual Studio build task. I have also tried selecting different visual studio versions but they all fail.

This appears to be happening across all the projects. I have web api and SQL projects. None of the build definitions are working anymore. All are throwing the project file does not exists error.

Comment: If the error message says "the project file does not exist", then that's the first thing you should investigate. Has source control been restructured recently? Have things been deleted? Outsiders on stack overflow have nothing to go off other than the information you've provided.

Comment: What's the task version (e.g. 1.*)? Can you reproduce this issue with a new build definition? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive (Set system.debug variable to true)?

Comment: This issue seems to have resolved it self. I guess there must have been some kind of update to VSTS. It was down for a couple of days and then started working all by itself.